# Android app that generates random words every second and displays them on screen

Tags: java, android

How can I make an android app that generates a random word every 1 second?
Here is my code:

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
            public void run()
            {
        started = true;
        word = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < lenght+1; i++)
        {
            int j = rand.nextInt((max-min) + 1) + min;
            word += tr.Translate(j);
        }
        txt.setText(word);
            }

    }, 0, 5000);
```

It seems that my app stops every time it must change the text of the TextView("txt"); how can I make this work?

Comment: you want random real words? or any sequence of character even if it has no meaning?

Comment: Any sequence of character even if it has no meaning.

Comment: What is your problem now? Can`t update the textView or can`t generate the words?

Comment: Can't update the textView because the app crashes when it must update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Undoubtfully, run this within a `Thread`. Doing this, it will generate the words in background and once it already has, the main UI thread must just append the content to the `txt` instance.

```
new Thread(
  new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
      // your stuff
    }
  }
).start()
```

To assign the result to the `txt` object, you'll probably be unable to do it within this thread. To do so, you'll need to declare a `Handler` in your `Activity` and use that handler within your thread, so it uses `sendMessage()` to the main Activity and the Activity just sets the text.

More on this [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

**---- EDIT ----**

As @FD_ says, there is another way to do the update without the use of a `Handler`. You would just need to call the `runOnUiThread()` method, something like this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    txt.setText(your_new_text);
  }
});
```

Another way is using an `AsyncTask`, which is (talking vaguely) an "evolution" of a thread which makes a lot of stuff for you. More on `AsyncTask`s [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

**---- EDIT ----**

This would be one of the ways:

```
new Thread(
  new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
      new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run()   {
          started = true;
          word = "";
          for (int i = 0; i < lenght+1; i++)
          {
            int j = rand.nextInt((max-min) + 1) + min;
            word += tr.Translate(j);
          }

          // This will update your txt instance without the need of a Handler
          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
              txt.setText(word);
            }
          });
        }
      }, 0, 5000);
    }
  }).start();
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `runOnUiThread()` instead of the Handler.

Comment: Don't use `AsyncTask` for timed actions.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    int i = 0;

public void changeString() {
    started = true;
    word = "";

    int j = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    word += tr.Translate(j);

    txt.setText(word);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (i < lenght + 1) {
                changeString();
                i++;
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

You can do this using timer as well

```
int i=0;
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
        public void run()
        {
    started = true;
    word = "";
    int j = rand.nextInt((max-min) + 1) + min;
    word += tr.Translate(j);
    txt.setText(word);
    i++
        }

}, 0, 5000);
```

try the above. The mistake you were making is using a for loop inside run instead use loop run method it-self.