# Android Studio rewrite screen

Tags: java, android

I would like to write a game for my android mobile phone. I am using Android Studio and I miss the repaint() funktions from eclipse.

I have a few 1 dight numberimages and they spawn on a linear layout in a random order. My idea was to generate a random number, show it on the screen and then generate another one ... 19863 times in a for-loop.

The problem is my display doesent show all numbers from my loop. First my smartphone goes through all 19863 random numbers and then it shows just the last one.

I already tried to start the same activity again and give it the necessary parameter but it didnt work because u have to start another activity not the same one (startActivity(intend i) ).

Thanks for any kind of help

Rechnungsobjekt is an object from class Rechnungen. zahl1 and zahl2 are integers to safe the random generated numbers through Rechnungen.
That part isnt very important.
zahl[0-9] are ImageViews in my Layout. drawable[0-9] are numberimages in my drawable folder drawaylbe_pluszeichen is a image of a plus.

I set a image to a ImageView in my layout.

Comment: Can you please provide code that you are having this issue with?

Comment: "and I miss the repaint() funktions from eclipse" the choice of ide doesn't affect what functions are available to you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Bob I modified my code. Thanks for your comment weston, I am new to Android Studio and Java and I get the  message that the repaint() function isn't valid in Android Studio.

Comment: I don't see anything called `repaint` in the code you have provided. What is the exact message? I doubt it just says "isn't valid".

Comment: Are you trying to create like a fast display counter that shows random numbers in place and then finally settles on a number, like maybe a random timer? Not clear what you want.

Comment: @weston: in eclipse u have a repiant() function. If you use it eclipse repaints the screen. To make a repaint make sense you can use for example a drawline() funktion with diffrent paramters every time (before) you repaint the screen. Android Studio works somehow diffrent?

Comment: Show some code that uses the repaint() function because at the moment it's unclear what you are talking of.

Comment: Eclipse and Studio are just different IDEs. The code they are able to compile is identical.

Comment: @Slartibartfast: yes, (later I will implement a sleep funktion so you have time to watch the screen) I try to create such a fast display counter. I want it to create random numbers they appear on the screen as soon they got generated                                           _____________________________________weston: I dont use a repaint() funktion. I can't or I am not able to do it in Android Studio. I did it in eclipse some time ago and it went well (a simply pong game). I want to repaint the screen on my android. I want a moving screen like a video what reloads my images fast.

Comment: "I did it in eclipse some time ago and it went well" Show that then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to display a fast display random counter that changes images in place every few seconds X number of times. In that case just create a Runnable and a Handler to change this image view every few seconds, since eventually to show the animation you will need a sensible delay between displays.

So start using it directly with handlers or use runOnUIThread

Some tutorials here: [Android app that generates random words every second and displays them on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21511850/android-app-that-generates-random-words-every-second-and-displays-them-on-screen)
and
here: [Change ImageView after few seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741458/change-imageview-after-few-seconds)

Comment: Thank you Slartibartfast. That was what I meant :) I made a new class with  runOnUIThread and reopened onCreate in it